# Tracking state changes in ViewStore of a parent component

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

I have 2 components: a `ParentComponent` which renders a `ChildComponent`

Parent component has a `ParentViewStore` and child component has `ChildViewStore`,

Is there a way to track `ParentViewStore` property changes in `ChildViewStore` **without** using `React.Component` lifecycle methods (e.g. `ComponentWillReceiveProps()`)?

Example code:

```
class ParentViewStore{
    @observable a;
}

class ChildViewStore{
    /* 
       code to run when 
       ParentViewStore.a 
       changes
    */
}
```

Code inside the `ChildViewStore` constructor runs only once, subsequent re-renders do not trigger the constructor again. `ParentViewStore` is passed as a prop to `ChildViewStore`

What I've tried:

```
class ChildViewStore{
    @observable parentProperty;

    constructor(props){
        this.parentProperty = props.parentViewStore.parentProperty
        observe(this.parentProperty, (change) => {
            console.log("change")
        });
    }
}
```

but this throws `[mobx] Cannot obtain administration from [parentPropertyValue]`

Comment: What do you want to do with the state changes? Re-render when it changes, or do some custom logic?

Comment: @Tholle, do some custom logic. It will always re-render when ParentComponent changes

Comment: What the point of avoiding component lifecycle ? You can use `reaction` in `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [`autorun`](https://mobx.js.org/refguide/autorun.html) in the constructor of `ChildViewStore` to run some custom logic every time `a` in the `ParentViewStore` instance is changed.

**Example**

```
class ChildViewStore{
    constructor(props){
        autorun(() => {
            console.log(`a changed: ${props.parentViewStore.a}`);
        });
    }
}
```